# Spring MVC 3.2.8 - Radio Buttons

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a project based in Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework. The version of the Spring Web model-view-controller (MVC) framework is 3.2.8
I have a JSP submitting a form

In this option I see the radio button checked

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="basic-url"><fmt:message key="criteria" />:</label>                                                                                                        
    <form:radiobuttons items="${deviceForm.device.productGroup.criteria}" 
        path="device.criteria"/>                                                    
</div>
```

but not in this one

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <c:forEach items="${deviceForm.device.productGroup.criteria}" var="criteria">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <form:radiobutton path="device.criteria" />
                <label for="basic-url">Criteria code:</label>
                 <input value="${criteria.code}" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"/>
                <label for="basic-url">Adoption date:</label>
                <input value="<fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${criteria.adoptionDate}"/>" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"/>
                <label for="basic-url">Expiration ate:</label>
                <input value="<fmt:formatDate type="date" value="${criteria.expirationDate}"/>" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>                                                
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you also describe the problem that your are experiencing.

Comment: the same path, first piece of code is working fine with the radio checked, not the second piece of code, even should be the same

Comment: try <form:radiobutton path="criteria.device.criteria" />

Comment: Invalid property 'criteria' of bean class ......